# What is best practice to remove values in M2M relation in DRF?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

could you please point this out...

What is the **best practice** in django rest framework should be if I wanna remove some m2m objects from base model object?

Should I just be satisfied with views method PATCH and update method in serializers (**orm m2m method "set" to reset and install all values from scratch**) and to use `obj.m2m.set(*[list_values])` OR should I implement a views action method DELETE to remove specific values (orm m2m method "remove" to remove specified in list objects) and to use `obj.m2m.remove(*[list_of_values])`?